# How to change the border color of a TextInput ( ActionScript 3.0 )?

Tags: actionscript-3, textinput

i was told to set the focus border from blue to red when my user floods the chat and i have everything ready for me to change that color but i just can't find the right method.

Here is my code:

```
this.input = new TextInput();
input.maxChars = 150;
var txtFormat:TextFormat = KingDialogStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE.getTextStyleClone();
txtFormat.color = 0x000000;
txtFormat.align = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

input.setStyle("textFormat", txtFormat);
input.alpha = 0.8;
input.visible = true;
input.width = 400;
input.x = 30;   
this.addChild(input);
```

I already tried to input.borderColor ( which doesn't seem to be right ) and input.setStyle("borderColor", 0xFF0000) but nothing seems to work.

I am clicking on the input and it shows a blue/cyan border and i need to change it to red sometimes just that, can anyone help me i really ain't finding anything...

Comment: Have you tried input.textField.border = true and input.texField.borderColor = 0xff0000; ?

Comment: This worked but the cyan border still remains, it is like other border like focus border i don't know and i need to change this focus border not the box border, i will put an image of it

Comment: Oh sorry i need 10 reputation to post images -.-, but well the problem is that when i click in this editBox, that's called textInput in as3, it displays a cyan border arround it to feedback the focus and when i flood to much i need that to become blue ( the focus border not the box border ) and i'm failling finding a way